OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow: no client credentials user enabled but the user is authorized
this is my first question here.
For starters, I've read all the other questions here, but I couldn't solve the problem.
The thing is, I had been using the sandbox environment without any major problems. Now, I was trying to connect to the production environment, and I can't get past the "invalid_grant: no client credentials user enabled (400)" error.
I have all the same configuration in both environments, but the sandbox with the sandbox credentials works and the production environment doesn't.
It is in a Rails application that uses the Salesforce API with the restforce gem and the client credentials flow. I have all the environment variables defined, and the user is authorized. Do you know what could be the problem?

Update
I found the solution in another forum, I was using the wrong "Run As" prompt to set the user. Instead of using the one under "App Manager", you have to access Manage Connected Apps > App > Edit Policies and there click on Run As under the label Client Credentials Flow

Sanity check: The client secret and the client id are going to be different in your sandbox and production (unless you "install" the connected app from one org into the other, usually from prod into sandbox rather than the other way around, by going through a flow that can generate a refresh token like the Web-Server flow, a.k.a. the Authorization Code flow). Are they different in your ruby configuration?

Also, the user to use for the client credentials flow is not set on the screen you've included in your screenshot. You'd need to set that through the page you'd get to by clicking the "Manage" button. (Setup -> Managed Apps -> Connected Apps in the Classic UI, Setup -> Apps -> Connected Apps -> Manage Connected Apps in the Lightning UI). Not sure if the client credentials user is something that would be transferred over when installing a connected app in a different org, but my gut feeling says "no, you'd need to manually configure that in the new org". Error suggests that's the case too.

Does this answer your question? OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow: no client credentials user enabled

I know, I have created the connected app in the production environment from scratch and used those credentials. And the user is set, it appears under Custom Connected App Handler.

@VerónicaIsoardi The user for the app handler is not relevant to this error. You've got Derek's comment pointing you in the right direction and a detailed Q&A showing you the correct solution. Give it a shot.

That was it, thanks!
